# How to attach two raspberry pi zero w together with sepatate independent displays?

Tags: pi-zero-w, connection, cluster

How do I attach two raspberry pi zero w's together with sepatate independent displays to function as "one computer with extended display on two panels"?

The two displays are HDMI with usb touch (7 inch waveshare). So if I link the two pis together by USB, will I loose touch capabilities?

If that doesn't work, is there an SPI to HDMI adapter available I can use?

Thanks

Comment: I think you will struggle to make them function _exactly_ as one computer. To what extent do you really need them to function as one computer? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: If your goal is to be able to use a single keyboard/mouse I would use Synergy, great program that lets you share your keyboard/mouse with many different computers with their own monitors(but the mouse moves between monitors like you expect from multiple monitors)  A networked USB drive would give you storage that was accessible from both. But getting the two processors to work together is where it would get tricky and it would really depend on what you are trying to do.